# How to add second level indices to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
 d={'col1':{('a','aaa'):1,
          ('a','bbb'):2,
          ('b','bbb'):1,
          ('b','ccc'):2} }
 df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to change the dataframe, so that it will have all `'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'` 2nd level indices for both 'a' and 'b' 1st level indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `unstack` with `stack`

```
df = df.unstack().stack(dropna=False)
Out[82]: 
       col1
a aaa   1.0
  bbb   2.0
  ccc   NaN
b aaa   NaN
  bbb   1.0
  ccc   2.0
```